# android activity in kotlin is not created

Tags: android, kotlin

I have started a new Kotlin project in Android Studio. However, Kotlin code does not work. What I mean is when I run the app from my MainActivity written in Kotlin it is not even created and I get an empty screen with only an action bar. When I added Log.v(...) to the onCreate method of kotlin class, the log message did not show in logcat. What appears in logcat is:

```
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
```

Whereas when I run app from Activity written in Java everything works fine. I have added all the necessary dependencies, invalidated and rebuilt, no result.

project build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.21' apply false
}
```

app build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.driversupport'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.driversupport"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


    def nav_version = "2.5.3"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Feature module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"
}
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.driversupport.presentation.ui.activity

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import com.example.driversupport.R

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_DriverSupport)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_devices)
    }




}
```

Activity.java:

```
package com.example.driversupport.presentation.ui.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.driversupport.R;

public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_devices);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DriverSupport"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity android:name=".presentation.ui.activity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Does anybody know why app is not run in Kotlin?

Comment: Can you add exactly what is not working with kotlin ? Are you getting crash or error then add that stack trace here so we can identify issue

Comment: Why are you defined the second activity in `Java`? You did not add this activity value in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: @HalilOzel, I added it to show that code is identical. I tried to make either of them a starting activity in AndroidManifest.xml, and Activity.java runs properly, while running MainActivity.kt as starting activity ends up with empty screen.

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani, sorry, updated the question, I get an empty screen

Comment: You are using the wrong onCreate() method in Kotlin.  Use the one without the PersistableBundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like *Gregory Nowik* says in the comments, the problem is you're implementing [the wrong `onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)):

> `public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)`
>
> Same as `onCreate(android.os.Bundle)` but **called for those activities created with the attribute `R.attr.persistableMode` set to `persistAcrossReboots.`**

That's a special version of `onCreate` for apps that are set up a certain way - most people won't be doing that, so [*this* version of `onCreate` is called instead](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)):

> `protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)`
>
> Called when the activity is starting. This is where most initialization should go: **calling `setContentView(int)` to inflate the activity's UI**, using `findViewById(int)` to programmatically interact with widgets in the UI [...]

That's the method you need to override, the one that just takes a single `Bundle` parameter. Because you haven't overridden it, it's just the default implementation, which isn't calling `setContentView` with anything. That's why you get a blank `Activity` - you're not actually displaying a layout!

Answer (score -1):

You are using persistent in the wrong way.

> Persistence is "the continuance of an effect after its cause is removed".

Seeing that there is no code in your main activity the "persistent" is the state the app was on the last run..

Example: since you have no code in main activity, when you run the application it defaults to appearance (empty) as before.

In easy terms you are just calling the primary code from the last usage, example your app by default is blank. Your trying to run the design but persistent overrides the design and reverts back to blank.

What you need to do is drop all the persistent and then code as you would normally. Your app will run. Then when the "persistent" needs to be called then you add that to the later portion of onCreate.

This is to help point you in the right direction. Since I have no idea what your trying to `save` then call back.. I am assuming it's the design since you have nothing going on in the main activity.

Comment: This is a really confusing response and I'm not sure what it's supposed to mean. If *"persistent overrides the design"* means that `PersistableBundle` somehow overrides the results of `setContentView`, it doesn't - it's purely there for you to use if you stored state in it earlier. The superclass implementation just calls `onCreate(Bundle)` (https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java;l=1729;drc=14acc23d6e36f2aeec964382baffc96732435a94) which doesn't touch the content view either. This method isn't called, is the problem

Comment: @cactustictacs The OP is using the wrong onCreate. He is trying to use persistent to call his views apparently at startup.. by using persistent on onCreate and main activity is blank it's just gonna show the default blank app

Comment: @cactustictacs I pretty much said what you said in simpler terms because the way it looks he may or may not understand fully the answer.. so he has a expanded scientific explanation and a straight forward explanation.. however your is a little confusing to me as well... However, we both said the same thing in a different way, he knows knows why it's blank